# Prettify the code using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using function `prettify()` I can print the html code very well formated, and I have read that this function prints even a broken html code properly (for example if the tag is opened but never closed, `prettify` helps to fix that). But only this function can do that or after loading the data to Beautiful Soup object like:
`soup = BeautifulSoup(data`),
causes that now the soup contains a code which is resistant for a broken html code.
For example if I have a broken code:

```
<body>
 <p><b>Paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

and I will load it to the BS object it is seen inside of soup object as above or as a fixed one?:

```
<body>
 <p><b>Paragraph.</b></p>
</body>
```

Comment: `.prettify()` doesn't fix broken HTML, the HTML parser BS is using does (or at least tries to). Is your goal to prettify valid HTML or to fix broken HTML? These are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML marekup is corrected at the time of creating the soup, not at the time of pretty-printing it. This is needed so that BeautifulSoup can navigate the document correctly.

As you can see below, the string representation of the soup contains corrected markup:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> text="""<body>
...  <p><b>Paragraph.</p>
... </body>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> str(soup)
'<body>\n<p><b>Paragraph.</b></p>\n</body>\n'
>>>
```

If you read the source for [`class BeautifulStoneSoup`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/3.2/view/head:/BeautifulSoup.py#L1039), you will find the following comment which addresses your broken markup:

```
    This class contains the basic parser and search code. It defines
    a parser that knows nothing about tag behavior except for the
    following:

      You can't close a tag without closing all the tags it encloses.
      That is, "<foo><bar></foo>" actually means
      "<foo><bar></bar></foo>".
```

And then [further down the source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/3.2/view/head:/BeautifulSoup.py#L1470), you can see that `BeautifulSoup` inherits from `BeautifulStoneSoup`.